# What is the hook used by company-mode to perform autocompletion?

Tags: completion, company-mode

According to `describe-key` (`C-h k`), every character I type runs `self-insert-command` and I suspect that `self-insert-command` calls some undocumented hook to perform text completition.

I am trying to debug [`company-mode`](http://company-mode.github.io), which occasionally fails to complete my input. So, `describe-function` says that `self-insert-command` calls `post-self-insert-hook`. I set it to `nil` and tried to type something that would be autocompleted — and it *was* completed anyway! In addition to this, `self-insert-command` calls `expand-abbrev` and `auto-fill-function`, but I tried to call both, and neither shows a popup text. So, it seems like every keypress runs some other hook used by `company-mode`.

I found that `company-complete-common` is the function that does autocompletition, so I set a breakpoint there to find this mysterious hook by using a backtrace. And… it didn't work! It works if I call `company-complete-common` interactively, but if I trigger completion by typing a character, and the same window pops up, the breakpoint is ignored!

I'm out of ideas, I hope somebody knows how this works.

Comment: I found in the `company.el` that `company-mode` sets some `company-pre-command` and  `company-post-command` to a `pre-command-hook`/`post-command-hook`, but these doesn't do autocompletition either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you invoke one of the completion commands directly (such as `M-x company-complete-common`), the completion maybe-happens and the popup is rendered in `company-post-command`.

It looks at the current command, sees if it satisfies the value of `company-begin-commands`, and calls `company--perform`.

The latter looks at the buffer contents, and checks whether the prefix value returned by the currently used backend satisfies `company-minimum-prefix-length`, if so then asks for completions from the backend.

If completions were found, `company-post-command` calls all currently configured frontends with an argument `post-command`. That's where the popup rendering happens.

When completion doesn't work (and you don't see any errors in `*Messages*`), check whether it works with `M-x company-complete-common`, at the same buffer position. If it does, you might need to figure out the exact command your keypress was calling (try `C-h k`), and then add it to `company-begin-commands`.

Comment: I came to the conclusion because for I am near of a character that triggers autocompletition, if I am press `M-:` and enter `(company-post-command)`, nothing happens.

Comment: That won't work; see the update.